# Is it possible to generate sprites in a square matrix form?

Tags: css-sprites

I want to create a new sprite for my page, and I'm wondering that whether we can create a sprite of 25 images in 5 rows and 5 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can generate a sprite sheet in any number of rows and columns you like. You access the particular sprite you want with CSS positioning, so it doesn't matter how many rows and columns you have, as long as you know the coordinates of each, this isn't an issue.